# Why did my <script> get mangled, and how can I keep from happening again?

Tags: tinymce

I was pulling something from `https://CJSHayward.com/books/` and found that it did not have any of the dynamically arranged titles. When I went to edit the page, I found a surprise.

I had originally entered a hand-typed:

```
<script src="/wp-content/javascripts/wrapped-book-table.cgi"></script>
```

However, while the SCRIPT tag was still there, it was mangled:

```
<script src="/wp-content/javascripts/wrapped-book-table.cgi" type="mce-no/type" data-mce-src="/wp-content/javascripts/wrapped-book-table.cgi"></script>
```

What converted the first into the second one, and what does "mce" refer to? This is not something I would have entered, and the type of "mce-no/type" probably defeated the JavaScript being treated in JavaScript.

(And what can I do to prevent the transformaation from recurring?)

Comment: just a quick question, did you add that into the post or into your template?

Comment: Lets repeat together, the editor is for content, not for code :(.

Comment: @MarkKaplun so true!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with TinyMCE. That is the standard text editor in WP. When you hit refresh whilst editing a page it adds those tags to javascript. https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/5f320ac2acda15902b0488df1b7d85bf5c24ef94

However it is marked as fixed some time ago (2015) so perhaps your site is not up to date? Or of course perhaps it has resurfaced!

Comment: ...downvote was for what?!

Answer (score 0):

> (And what can I do to prevent the transformaation from recurring?)

Start with not putting Javascript into your Editor.

Comment: What is the preferred way to add JavaScript to exactly one page? Thanks,

Comment: By assigning a custom page template to that specific page.